# I want a rich:modalPanel that doesnt block the windows behide it

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want a rich:modalPanel that doesnt block the windows behide it.

I didnt found anywhere, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just set modal="false" like

```
<rich:popupPanel id="nonModal" modal="false">
...
</rich:popupPanel>
```

MAG,
Milo van der Zee

Comment: I am using Rich 3, that dont have rich:popupPanel. But I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a style:

```
<style>
.noMaskClass .rich-mpnl-mask-div{
  display:none;
}
</style>
<rich:modalPanel  styleClass="noMaskClass" ... >
```